# How to create a new user with all privileges to connect remote database from localhost?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost, remote-access

I have created new user in localhost/phpmyadmin through home>users>adduser with

Username: NEW
Password: 123456

Also I checked the privileges. But it's not working when I log in with new username.

Help me to create new user with all privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read up on how to operate phpMyAdmin with it's official [documentation.](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/docs.php)

Comment: i have read and created new user with all privileges, and i need some idea about host field while creating new user, kindly share your knowledge

Comment: You can thank me by voting my answer up, and if my answer was correct by ticking it.

Answer (score 1):

I know the "console way":

```
CREATE USER NEW IDENTIFIED BY '123456';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO USER NEW WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

First line creates the user with wanted parameters.
Second line gives all permissions to user, and also sets the possibility to be admin/root.

Comment: If you're using phpMyAdmin, you can use the web console, write this lines and run them to get your result.

Comment: @SonyARG i have tried normally as per documentation, i have created man, thanks

Comment: just a sidenote if anyone lands on this, for the password it needs a ' ' around it for the right sql syntax.